# How do one observere if there is a curl or not in these vector fields?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I don't understand how I can observe which of these vector fields have a curl equal to zero. Can someone explain to me how it works?

[image]

Comment: Math insight is GOAT for this kind of stuff!
https://mathinsight.org/curl_idea

Comment: Thank you for the link! I will look at it and see if I understand it better :)

Comment: I'm sorry. But I still don't see where the curl is zero. I thought there might have to be some type of rotation in the vector field, so I thought that a) did not have curl (curl=0) and that d must have curl. But the solution says it is opposite :(

Comment: It's not that the vector field is itself turning (or not), it's whether a small square or circle will turn when dropped into that moving fluid. The changing magnitudes in both cases account for the presence of curl or its absence. (Take a little square with sides parallel to the axes in the first case and a curvilinear rectangle (one pair of sides along the circular arcs, the other pair orthogonal) and look at what happens to them.)

Comment: So after I have drawn these squares, you say that I must look at what happens to them. I'm not sure what I am looking for to be honest, after picturing the squares. I'm sorry for all the questions by the way, I just really want to understand this.

Comment: You should be seeing that the vector field makes them actually spin. For example, in a) the work done on the right exceeds (in magnitude) the negative work done on the left, and the square spins counterclockwise. In the case of d) there is zero net work (because the increased length of the circular arc compensates precisely for the smaller magnitude of the field) and the region does not spin.

Comment: The nature of your confusion suggests you missed the link to the page on subtleties about curl embedded within the "Don't get misled" box: https://mathinsight.org/curl_subtleties clarifies exactly your confusion about a and d. I recommend reading that box on the original page first for context.

Comment: Thank you @TedShifrin. I didn't think about the magnitude of the arrows, and that explains a lot. I think I understand it better now. Thank you again :)

Comment: @MarkS. Yes, I see now what is wrong about thinking that a) does not have a curl. I will read the websites again! Thank you for help :)